# what is the use of "searchstate" in fat wire

Tags: content-management-system, fatwire

What is the use of "**searchstate**" in fatwire?
All I know is that it is used to get data from DB.

Answer (score 2):

searchstate is used to filter the assets that you get from DB with assetset tag. You can create filters on attribute values or range of values.

In the next code we have a flexasset named "Event" with an attribute "startDate". We want to retrieve the events that start after 2013-01-01

<searchstate:create name="ss"/>
<searchstate:addrangeconstraint name="ss" typename="mySiteAttributeType" attribute="startDate" upperequal="2013-01-01 00:00:00"/>
<assetset:setsearchedassets name="as" constraint="ss" assettypes="Event"/>
<assetset:getassetlist name="as" listvarname="auxlist"/>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, searchstate is used to get data from DB. But what kind of data, what range of data and data to be cached or not. This type of information you can restrict while searching.

Searchstate is used to search assets in FatWire of types - Flex assets.

For more details, check the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29495_01/doc.1111/webcenter_sites_11gr1_bp1_developer_guide.pdf

Cheers!!